# When is this open sentence true? $Q(n): n^3 + n - 1 = 0$, where n is the collection of integers

Tags: logic, polynomials

I've asked my instructor but he didn't really help at all, and I can't find anything on the web that can help me since I'm not sure what the terms are.

Question:

**When is this open sentence true? $Q(n): n^3 + n - 1 = 0 $, where n is the collection of integers.**

I tried $ n=2, n=1, n=0, n=-1 $ and $n=-2 $ but none of those worked out, and going further from 0 in either direction would just get further and further off.

I told the instructor that I couldn't find any values that would make the open sentence true, which means it must always be false, and he told me to then prove that, but we haven't learned anything about that yet so I'm fairly confused.

Also, are these kinds of questions on math stack exchange allowed? If not, sorry about that.

Comment: Do you mean that $n$ is an integer?

Comment: @Dasherman Yes, I believe n is supposed to be an integer, since it says in the question that n is the collection of integers. I've posted all the information that I have in the question, aside from that I'd be guessing.

Comment: I think that this question about polinomials.

Comment: Yes, such questions are totally fine on the site. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no problem with the question, very fine question.

you need to proof that for every integer $ n^3 + n - 1 \not = 0 $

Maybe the easiest way is to proof that

$ n^3 + n \not = 1 \leftrightarrow $

$ ( n^2 + 1) n \not = 1  $

$ ( n^2 + 1) n$ is only 1 when both (for the same  $n$ ) are 1 or -1.

$ n^2+1 $ and $n$ cannot both be 1 (for the same  $n$ ) and 
$ n^2+1 $ and $n$ cannot both be -1 (for the same  $n$ )

so the condition is never fulfilled.
therefore the condition is never true.

A better method would be to factor $ n^3 + n -1 $ but i am not sure how to do this. (i am more a Logician than a mathemathician)

GOOD LUCK

Comment: you beat me to it...  +1

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I prefer to win on quality not on speed

Answer (score 2):

As integer roots of polynomial are divizors of free member so n|1 . So you only need to try values 1 and -1 .

Comment: But I tried both of those, 1^3 + 1 - 1 = 0 comes out to 1=0 which is false, and -1^3 + 1 -1 = 0 comes out to -1=0, which is also false. I need one to come out to true to answer the question, or prove somehow that it's never true.

Comment: Rational root theorem.  If there's s a rational root it will be either 1 or -1

Comment: @Alex Podworny , root of polinomail must be divizors of free member so if all divizors of free member aren't roots of polinomial than this polinomial have no integer roots.

Comment: @Alex Podworny , you wrong . f(-1)=-3 (not -1) .

Comment: @Antony How is it -3? (-1)*(-1)*(-1) would be -1, then add one to be 0, then minus one to be -1, am I missing something?

Comment: @Alex Podworny , $Q(-1)=(-1)^3+(-1)^1-1=-3$

Comment: @Antony Ah right, it is -3, my bad. As for accepting your solution, the solution that Willemien provided is making more sense to me right now, but once I have time to try and understand the answer more I'll decide who helped the most.